# Graph API - Unable to Use Valid Access Token to Upload file

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am unable to upload a file using a valid access token (the token allows me to list groups, drive items etc.). The error that appears is:

invalidRequest: One of the provided arguments is not acceptable.

Using the following PUT request:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{my group id}/drive/items/{my item(folder) id}:/test.txt:/content

using content type: text/plain

I tested this exact same request using the graph explorer https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer and my office 365 user account and the upload worked, so I though it might be an app permissions thing, however this did not work even after granting absolutely every permission to the app and regenerating the access tokem.
Please help as I would rather use an access token than my user account to perform the uploads.

Thankyou
Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve by creating a new app definition in Azure AD with the same permissions and it worked! Perhaps there was some corruption in my original Azure application - maybe the manifest was corrupt (due to a bug)?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a worked endpoint on my side:

```
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/my-group-id/drive/root:/test.txt:/content
```

Request body: `The contents of the file goes here.`

**The content type of request header does not need to be configured.**

You need to check your folder path too.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

However I tried your suggestion and still get the same issue. I tried just placing the test file in the root, exactly as you have done (this should work shouldn't it?). And it failed. I also remove the Content-Type header and no success.

I'm not sure where too look now as I am tempted just to use a different service like Dropbox to store my files.

Comment: Another question - did you use an authentication token or a user account to access the endpoint?

Comment: I use oauth token

Comment: Me too, however mine is a daemon style token (not attached to a user). Is yours also a user independent token? Perhaps this is where the issue lies?